# Not able to pass Data From Nested File Upload React Component to Parent Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have React Component which utilises a Material UI File Upload code, and this works well, and I can read the contents of a file that I upload. However, I am having difficulty is in passing this data up into the parent or hosted component as my aim is to then pass this data on to another component that is also hosted in this parent component. The parent is not going to make use of this data, and the reason for the separation is so I can use this File Upload else where and not tied down to anyone part of the application. Further, I am using React Hooks!!

So, below is just the main part of the code that handles the data read in from the file upload followed by the code that hosts the file upload component -

THIS IS THE CHILD COMPONENT (RELEVANT CODE ONLY) -

```
const FileUpload = props => { 
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile]= useState(null); 
const {data} = props;

const [results, setResults] = useState(null); 
let contentReader; 

const handleFileRead =(e)=>{ 
   setResults(contentReader.result);
   data(contentReader.results);
 }   

 const handleselectedFile=(e)=>{ 
    setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0].name) 

    contentReader = new FileReader(); 
    contentReader.onloadend = handleFileRead;
    contentReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]); 
  }
```

THIS IS THE PARENT OR HOST -

```
const Host = props => {


  const [childContent, setChildContent] = useState('');


  return (
     <React.Fragment>
      <Grid>
        <Grid>

          <div>
            </div>
              <Upload data={setChildContent}/>
            </div>
            <div>
              {console.log(childContent)}
            </div>
        </Grid>
       </Grid>
      )
    }
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

}

So, my question is when I click a button on my file upload, read in the content of the file and then pass on up to the parent or host, where I can this pass onto different component?

Comment: should be working, have you debugged that handleFileRead invokes and data is there as well as contentReader.results ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Putting a console.log on the content Reader.results output the results. Also if output results from useState in the return of the child component it shows the content. But if I put a console.log on results in handleFileRead it is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you have a typo?

```
contentReader.results
```

Shouldn't it be

```
contentReader.result
```

Here - `data(contentReader.results);`